# Gnuplot 5: color gradient shading between curves

Tags: colors, gnuplot, gradient

This was created with Matplotlib. Is it possible to make the same type of shading in Gnuplot 5?

[image: color gradient shading]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware that gnuplot has a gradient fill option, but I could be wrong.
The following is a bit of an "ugly" workaround. You basically create 3 plots on top of each other. You might want to adjust the palette to get the desired colors and a smooth transition.

1. a dummy plot to get the palette as background (i.e. the colorbox as large as the graph)
2. cover the part above `y>f(x)` and `y>0` to `x2`-axis as well as below `y<f(x)` and `y<0` to `x1`-axis.
3. plot again `f(x)` to see `f(x)` and the axes tics again

**Edit:**
The earlier version of the code used `multiplot`. It's not necessary, just use `set colorbox back`. But then `set xzeroaxis ls -1` is not visible anymore, add `plot 0 w l ls -1` instead.

**Code:**

```
### filled curve with gradient
reset session

f(x) = sin(x)/(1+x)
fabove(x) = f(x)<0 ? 0 : f(x)
fbelow(x) = f(x)>0 ? 0 : f(x)

set samples 200
set palette defined (0 "white", 1 "red", 2 "black")

set colorbox back user origin graph 0, graph 0 size graph 1, graph 1
unset cbtics

set xrange[0:15]
set xzeroaxis ls -1
set yrange[-0.2:0.5]

plot fabove(x) w filledcurves x2 fc rgb "white" not, \
     fbelow(x) w filledcurves x1 fc rgb "white" not, \
     f(x) w l lw 2 lc rgb "black", \
     NaN palette, \
     0 w l ls -1
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]