# gnuplot histogram with colour gradient

Tags: gnuplot, histogram, gradient

I tried to plot with following data with 2 (lower) and 3 (upper)

Data:

```
Cl  5.1244    6.0975
Cl2 3.6397    5.0368
Cl3 4.9153    6.0568
Br  4.7905    5.2973
Br2 3.4454    4.3466
Br3 4.6047    5.2715
I   4.5664    4.6143
I2  3.3487    3.7660 
I3  4.4178    4.6079
```

Code:

```
set border 2
set yrange [1.5:8.5]
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1
set style fill solid
#set palette defined (0 "white", 7.0 "red")
#set boxwidth 0.5
set xtics format ""

plot "CBM-VBM2.dat" using ($2):xtic(1), '' u 3
```

cbm-vbm-plot

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! So, what is your question? I can't find a question mark in your question. I am not aware that gnuplot has boxes with color gradients. Here is an awkward workaround for a curve with gradient fill https://stackoverflow.com/a/60158377/7295599 but I don't see this approach for multiple boxes. I guess you have to split all your boxes into subboxes and plot them with different (graded) colors. I guess this would be pretty lengthy and cumbersome but should be feasible

Comment: Question answered? Problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it didn't get that lengthy as I expected. Find attached a suggestion for how to create boxes with gradients.
In order to get a good looking graph and fading, you might want to tweak a few variables, e.g. `N` for the number of subboxes or the "fading function", here `sqrt(x)`.

**Code:**

```
### gradient boxes
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1   1L   5.45   3.90   0x000000
2   2L   5.00   4.00   0x008888
3   3L   4.90   4.10   0xff00ff
4   4L   4.80   4.12   0x0000ff
5   5L   4.75   4.15   0x00ff00
EOD

$Levels <<EOD
Ti         4.35
Cu         4.70
Ni         5.23
Pt         5.64
graphene   4.50
EOD

ColorFade(x) = sqrt(x)                 # function between [0:1][0:1] to fade out the color
BoxWidth  = 0.9                        # relative boxwidth
BoxHeight = 0.3                        # fade-box height
N = 21                                 # number of subbox steps
FadeDirection(col) = col==3 ? -1 : 1   # fading direction
BaseColor(n) = int(word($Data[n],5))   # base color

set print $FadeBoxes append
do for [a=1:|$Data|] {
    do for [col=3:4] {
        do for [i=0:N] {
            x0 = a
            y0 = -word($Data[a],col)
            ystep = real(BoxHeight)/N*FadeDirection(col)
            print sprintf("% 9g % 9g % 9g % 9g 0x%02x%06x", \
            x0-BoxWidth/2., x0+BoxWidth/2., \
            y0+i*ystep,       y0+(i+1)*ystep, \
            int(ColorFade(real(i)/N)*0xff),BaseColor(a))
        }
    }
}
set print

set style fill solid noborder
unset key
LevelXShift = 6

plot $FadeBoxes u 1:3:1:2:3:4:5 w boxxy fc rgb var ti "Levels", \
     $Data      u 1:(-$3):2 w labels offset 0, 0.7, \
     $Levels u ($0/2+LevelXShift):(-$2):1 w labels offset 0, 0.7, \
          '' u ($0/2+LevelXShift):(-$2):2 w labels offset 0,-0.7, \
          '' u ($0/2+LevelXShift-0.2):(-$2):(0.4):(0) w vec lc "red" lw 2 nohead
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: excellent, I will go through the code to understand

Comment: @RajeevKumar so, did you have time to understand? Question answered?